# Can Fody and its plugins be used with .NET Core (3.0)?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, fody, fody-propertychanged

As the title says, I'm having trouble getting [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), and the plugin [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), to work in .NET Core 3.0, or any .NET Core version. Reading the issues on the respective GitHub pages doesn't answer my question, nor am I able to find any relevant answers.

Once installed I cannot run my WPF project anymore and I am given the following error:

```
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.
Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core.
This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[21820] CalculationToolsApp.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I found out that I (maybe) cant use "Fody.Costura" with "Fody.PropertyChanged" like this in the FodyWeavers.xml file:

```
<Weavers>
  <PropertyChanged />
  <Costura />
</Weavers>
```

Which shouldn't be a problem because with .NET Core I can create a single file application anyway. Removing the Costura reference from the FodyWeavers.xml solved my problem!

Comment: `Fody` is compatible with .NET Core 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. Fody is compatible with .NET Standard.

- Create a new WPF app using the `WPF App (.NET Core)` template in Visual Studio 2019 or using the `dotnet new wpf` command
- Install the `Fody` and `PropertyChanged.Fody` NuGet packages
- Add a file named "FodyWeavers.xml" with the following contents to the project:

  ```
  <Weavers>
      <PropertyChanged />
  </Weavers>
  ```
- Build

If you then decompile the assembly using a decompiler such as for example [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), you should see the injected code as expected, e.g.:

```
public string GivenNames
{
    // Method get_GivenNames with token 06000009
    get
    {
        return this.<GivenNames>k__BackingField;
    }
    // Method set_GivenNames with token 0600000A
    set
    {
        if (string.Equals(this.<GivenNames>k__BackingField, value, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return;
        this.<GivenNames>k__BackingField = value;
        this.<>OnPropertyChanged(<>PropertyChangedEventArgs.FullName);
        this.<>OnPropertyChanged(<>PropertyChangedEventArgs.GivenNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me solve the problem. I have edited my question with my solution!

Answer (score 1):

Costura didnt work in wpf with .net core 3.1 for me either.
In .net core 3.1 you can use this instead:

- Build -> publish -> create profile -> Edit "Configuration"
- Target Runtime = win-x64 (or what ever target system you want, but NOT "portable")
- expand "File Publish Options"
- check: Produce single file
- save

When you now choose build -> publish -> publish button it will create the single file.

It seems to be that they stopped the costura project because of the "Single-file executables" feature of .net core. Though this feature is still behind costura because you have to set a target runtime.

https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/442

> In dotnet core 3 there are two new features
>
> ```
> Single-file executables
> Assembly linking
> ```
>
> With these features included in the dotnet tool set, the value
> proposition of Costura is greatly diminished. With that in mind I
> think long term Costura should cease to be used as people transition
> over.
>
> Please comment with any input.
>
> Plan:
>
> ```
> disable issues
> PR will still be accepted but only for bug fixes
> add note to readme
> add note to nuget description
> write a warning in
> ```

**update for .NET 5:**
for .NET 5 and the current visual studio version 16.10.2 the wizard changed. I could not get this to work with the wizard anymore though i checked the options for single file etc.. But using the console worked: tools -> command line -> developer command prompt -> enter this:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true
```

[.NET 5 not compiling to single file executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133771/net-5-not-compiling-to-single-file-executables/65418065#65418065)