# Including symbols in a single file bundle is not supported when publishing for .NET5 or higher

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I try to publish a .net Core (WinForms) project, which I upgraded from core3.0 to net5.0, as Single Exe.

I get the following error:

```
NETSDK1142: Including symbols in a single file bundle is not supported when publishing for .NET5 or higher.
```

researching NETSDK1142 I do not get any results in google regarding a fix.

With Core3.0 the following command worked:

```
dotnet publish nameofproject.csproj \
   -o bin/Release/core \
   -c Release \
   -p:Platform=x64 \
   -r win-x64 \
   --self-contained true
```

I also tried the following flags for net5.0. Still getting the same error even with `DebugSymbols=false`

```
dotnet publish nameofproject.csproj \
    -o bin/Release/core \
    -c Release \
    -p:Platform=x64 \
    -p:NoWarn=CS0618 \
    -p:NoWarn=NU1605 \
    --self-contained true \
    -p:PublishSingleFile=true \
    -p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true \
    -p:PublishReadyToRun=true \
    -p:PublishTrimmed=false \
    -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true \
    /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false
```

Comment: Looks like you [need an explicit RuntimeIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133771/net-5-not-compiling-to-single-file-executables)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen adding ` -r win-x64` did not work for me

Comment: Did you try specifying it in the project file instead?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I did not try to change the project file. I fixed the issue by setting another rather unkown flag to not Include Symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

just add `-p:IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile=false` or `/p:IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile=false` to the publish command

### How I found it

After trying to fix the issue since 2 days the solution was found in the [dotnet/sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) Source Code.

in [`sdk/src/Tasks/Common/Resources/Strings.resx`](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/ae37ab27e951312c2655b87c43faa20e3985948c/src/Tasks/Common/Resources/Strings.resx#L673) I found the error string

```
  <data name="CannotIncludeSymbolsInSingleFile" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>NETSDK1142: Including symbols in a single file bundle is not supported when publishing for .NET5 or higher.</value>
    <comment>{StrBegin="NETSDK1142: "}</comment>
  </data>
```

then I tracked down the `CannotIncludeSymbolsInSingleFile` string resource in the sourcecode and found the following result in [`sdk/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets`](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/e2687a3e6e5259d2167173977e64f1e9ab91f51b/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets#L98)

```
<NETSdkError Condition="'$(PublishSingleFile)' == 'true' And
                            '$(IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile)' == 'true' And
                            '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' >= '5.0' And '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp'"
                 ResourceName="CannotIncludeSymbolsInSingleFile" />
```

There I found the Flag I had to set on build `IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile`